# Can't knitr to html

Tags: r

I keep getting the following error message

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : trying to use CRAN without setting a 
mirror calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages 
-> contrib.url
```

I have tried lots of things, including

```
install.packages("rlang")
install.packages("knitr")
install.packages("rmarkdown")
options(repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")
```

I also tried

```
install.packages("contrib.url")
library(contrib.url)
```

which gave the error message

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘contrib.url’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Comment: I don't know of a *package* named `contrib.url`, but there is the `utils::contrib.url` *function*. Is that what you mean to use?

Comment: If you remove the `install.packages("contrib.url")` portion (and the errors it produces), I think we need to return to the original question: your document is not knitting into HTML. My guess (from the error and its helpful hint) is that you need to specify a mirror before installing new packages. (That is, try moving your `options` expression to *before* the `install.packages` lines.)

Comment: I can reproduce this problem in a non-interactive R session by calling `contrib.url("@CRAN@")`. (I suspect that your installation of R is defaulting `getOption("repos")` to `"@CRAN@"`.) When interactive (e.g., RStudio or Rterm), it asks me which of the (currently 77) mirrors I want to use; when not interactive (e.g., while knitting a document), it cannot ask you, so it will error. The order of operations is clear, you must set the `repos=` option to a specific mirror *before* trying to install anything.

Comment: @r2evans this fixed it for me! thanks